# Finding indices of 2D array with two constraints

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

I have two 2D arrays in NumPy of equal size, and am trying to identify the indices where two conditions are met. Here's what I try and what I get. Any suggestions? I'm using `np.where` and this does not seem to be the correct choice.

Thanks for any help.

```
ind_direct_pos = np.where((bz_2D_surface3 > 0.0) and (jz_2D_surface3 > 0.0))
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: try  : `np.where((bz_2D_surface3 >0) & (jz_2D_surface3 >0))`

Comment: this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

If the two arrays with **the same size**, not the same shape, we can `ravel` it at first (using `and` instead `&` is a cause of this problem as [I'mahdi comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1740577/imahdi)):

```
bz_2D_surface3 = np.array([[1, 3], [4, -1], [-3, -6], [-1, 2], [1, 3], [2, -3]])
jz_2D_surface3 = np.array([[-1, 3, 3], [-4, -1, 2], [3, -1, -5], [1, 2, 3]])

# pair_wise
np.transpose(np.where((bz_2D_surface3.ravel() > 0) & (jz_2D_surface3.ravel() > 0)))
# [[ 1]
#  [ 2]
#  [ 9]
#  [10]]
```

if we have two arrays with **the same shape**:

```
bz_2D_surface3 = np.array([[1, 3], [4, -1], [-3, -6], [-1, 2], [1, 3]])
jz_2D_surface3 = np.array([[-1, 3], [-4, -1], [3, -1], [1, 2], [1, 11]])

# pair_wise
np.transpose(np.where((bz_2D_surface3 > 0) & (jz_2D_surface3 > 0)))
# [[0 1]
#  [3 1]
#  [4 0]
#  [4 1]]

# row_wise
np.where(((bz_2D_surface3 > 0.0).all(1)) & ((jz_2D_surface3 > 0.0).all(1)))[0]
# [4]
```